# Byte array to hexadecimal and back again in JavaScript

Tags: cryptography, javascript

I can generate a byte array with

```
var myByteArray = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))
```

and I get

```
181,143,16,173,231,56,63,149,181,185,224,124,84,230,123,36
```

I can then turn this into a string with

```
cryptoHelpers.convertByteArrayToString(myByteArray);
```

and i get

```
µ­ç8?µ¹à|Tæ{$
```

But what I really want is a 128 bit hexadecimal like...

```
6a3e52297b2e593f4d506f7164
```

And I want to be able to go back from hexadecimal to a byte array.

Is there a copy and paste function or library to make this magic happen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to Bitcoin.

Comment: You should ask this question on Stackoverflow, however search first.  I'm positive the answer will already exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, the question, as written, does not appear related to bitcoin. Perhaps there is a relation, but if so, it should be made explicit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's something you can copy-paste in.

```
byteArray = new Uint8Array([181,143,16,173,231,56,63,149,181,185,224,124,84,230,123,36]);
function toHexString(byteArray) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(byteArray, function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');
}
function toByteArray(hexString) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < hexString.length; i += 2) {
    result.push(parseInt(hexString.substr(i, 2), 16));
  }
  return result;
}
hexString = toHexString(byteArray);
byteArray = toByteArray(hexString);
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603205/how-to-convert-hex-string-into-a-bytes-array-and-a-bytes-array-in-the-hex-strin)/[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309988/byte-array-to-hex-string-conversion-in-javascript).

Comment: Using the above I'm getting a string that is not 128bits 289332005600940420022031 if I console log myByteArray i get an array buffer like "Uint8Array(16) [181, 143, 16, 173, 231, 56, 63, 149, 181, 185, 224, 124, 84, 230, 123, 36]" how do i convert this to an array?

Comment: @Will-In-China See edit.

Comment: toByteArray get wrong values when hex-string contains an odd number of characters: "fff", "1AB"

Comment: @Geograph since each byte is 2 hex digits, this is expected behaviour - a hex string with an odd number of digits is in invalid hex string.